# Linq group by issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

Hi I got issue with my record. I get the duplicate record as below. I using telerik radgrid hierachy to display the data. It can expandable then show the service available.

```
MerchantID  MerchantName BranchID BranchName
1001         AAA          B01         BBB
1001         AAA          B01         BBB
```

Here are my codes. Please help. Thanks

```
 Public Function GetMerchantList(ByVal aMerchant As TT_MERCHANT, ByVal aMerchantService As TT_MERCHANT_SERVICE) As List(Of MerchantApp)
        Dim Db As New TTMSEntities

        Dim Data = (From p In Db.TT_MERCHANT Join r In Db.TT_BRANCH_SETTING On _
                   p.MERCHANT_BRANCH_INTERNAL_NUM Equals r.INTERNAL_NUM Join t In Db.TT_MERCHANT_SERVICE On t.MERCHANT_INTERNAL_NUM Equals p.INTERNAL_NUM
                   Select New MerchantApp With {
                                       .InternalNum = p.INTERNAL_NUM,
                                       .MerchantID = p.MERCHANT_ID,
                                       .MerchantName = p.DESCRIPTION,
                                       .BranchID = r.BRANCH_ID,
                                       .BranchName = r.BRANCH_DESC,
                                       .ServiceID = t.MERCHANT_SERVICE_ID,
                                       .ServiceName = t.DESCRIPTION})

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(aMerchant.MERCHANT_ID) Then
                Data = Data.Where(Function(x) x.MerchantID = aMerchant.MERCHANT_ID)
            End If

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(aMerchant.DESCRIPTION) Then
                Data = Data.Where(Function(x) x.MerchantName.Contains(aMerchant.DESCRIPTION))
            End If

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(aMerchant.ISACTIVE) Then
                Data = Data.Where(Function(x) x.Status = aMerchant.ISACTIVE)
            End If

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(aMerchantService.MERCHANT_SERVICE_ID) Then
            Data = Data.Where(Function(x) x.ServiceID = aMerchantService.MERCHANT_SERVICE_ID)
        End If

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(aMerchantService.DESCRIPTION) Then
            Data = Data.Where(Function(x) x.ServiceName = aMerchantService.DESCRIPTION)
        End If


        Return Data.ToList()
    End Function
```

Comment: There is nothing apparent in the code your supplied that is causing duplicates. I think you need to put in some trace code on the output of the function to make sure the duplication is happening there. If not it could be being caused when you add the results to the UI. If it is happening in the function it is because of the data in the database and not your code.

Comment: Also you should be using a `Using` to dispose of your entities before you exit the function. It's not causing duplication, but you could have a nasty memory leak or resource issue if you don't dispose of the entities.

Comment: possibly you need [Distinct extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348456(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Still not solve. Can I use group by ?

Comment: When you join parents and children the parents tend to get duplicated. I don't understand why everything seems to get duplicated. Are there duplicate rows in the database?